# Stopping VNC on headless Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, vnc

How do I completely stop X11VNC and have it not restart at startup on my headless Ubuntu 18.04 server?

I am worried about it being a security risk.

There is this process running:
`/usr/bin/x11vnc`

and it logging this repeatedly in the `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]:  --- x11vnc loop: 6360540 ---
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]:  --- x11vnc loop: waiting for: 4966
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]: 06/11/2018 06:12:43 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbauth
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]: 06/11/2018 06:12:43 passing arg to libvncserver: /home/said/.vnc/passwd
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]: 06/11/2018 06:12:43 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbport
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]: 06/11/2018 06:12:43 passing arg to libvncserver: 5900
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]: 06/11/2018 06:12:43 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10  pid: 4966
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]: xauth:  unable to generate an authority file name
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]: 06/11/2018 06:12:43 -auth guess: failed for display='unset'
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]: 06/11/2018 06:12:43 -auth guess: since we are root, retrying with FD_XDM=1
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]: 06/11/2018 06:12:43 -auth guess: failed for display='unset'
Nov  6 06:12:43 Taurasi x11vnc[1292]:  --- x11vnc loop: sleeping 2000 ms ---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [1292] after the name is the Process ID, or PID. If it's a service that is automatically starting at boot up, you will need to use systemctl:

```
systemctl stop x11vnc
systemctl disable x11vnc
```

I'm not sure what the actual service name is for x11vnc so you'll likely need to type x or x11 and tab to see what autocompletes.